# Do I need a visa for a connecting international flight in Guangzhou, China?

Tags: visas, china

I am a US citizen and I will be flying New York → Guangzhou → Seoul. The only thing I plan to do in Guangzhou is get off one plane and get on to another. Will I need a visa for this?

Comment: Short answer: Yes within 72 hours for US citizen in Guangzhou Baiyun Airport. Check the official info in Chinese http://cs.mfa.gov.cn/wgrlh/lhqz/cjwdn_660600/t1175678.shtml

Comment: @JohnHass - most of us can't read Chinese (in which your linked page is written), but the 72 hour transit visa is for people with long layovers who want to leave the airport.  It is not needed for people simply changing planes.

Comment: I mean "yes, you can stay without a visa."

Comment: The possible duplicate does not answer this question for two reasons: 1) Guangzhou airport is not listed in the answer 2) the other Q is about a long layover > 24h whereas here is a short transit. Close-voters abstain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are flying through on the same airline or partner airlines and your bags are checked through, then no visa needed. (CZ-CZ or CZ-KE)

If by chance you are changing carriers / alliances, you need to ask the airline originating in New York if they can check your bags through to the connecting airline.

If the bags can not be checked through you will need a transit permit go claim your bags and then check them in for your next flight.

Comment: Even if the bags aren't checked through no visa is required.  A US citizen can use the 72 hour visa-free transit at Guangzhou.

Comment: I back the comment by @Doc, care to make than an answer or edit Tom's answer?

Comment: Edited the wording, but the transit permit still requires advance preparation - notifying the airline in advance of your intentions to transit landside and the airline subsequentially notifying the Chinese government.  I believe Beijing is the only airport where you can do everything after arrival.

Comment: @Tom thanks for editing, +1! Do you have any sources regarding the transit permit (not doubting you, just new to me and curious)? I.e. you get it from the airline in advance (when first checking in) and then use that thing to pass immigration, collect and re-check your bags and pass exit controls of immigration again? Could you edit your question to incorporate that info?

Comment: Guangzhou info - http://www.gbiac.net/72hours/en/index.html  Each airport has info posted on their website and not all airports follow the same procedures.